# Forbidden syscall rt_sigprocmask in program to check if a string can be completely made up of smaller given strings

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a code which was to be evaluated by an online judge:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

#define DICT_LENGTH 10

int dictionary_contains(char *s, char dict[][10]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<DICT_LENGTH;i++){
        if(!strcmp(dict[i], s))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool break_word(char *s, char dict[][10])
{
    int j;
    int len  = strlen(s);
    if(len==0)
    {
        //printf("1YES");
        return true;
    }
    bool wb[len+1];
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<len+1;k++)
    {
        wb[k]=false;
    }

    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=len; i++)
    {
        char *prefix = (char *)malloc(i+2);
        strncpy(prefix,s, i);
        prefix[i] = '\0';


        if(wb[i]==false && dictionary_contains(prefix,dict))
        {
            wb[i]=true;
            //printf("%s",prefix);
            //printf("%d",i);
        }
        if(wb[i]==true)
        {
            //printf("%d",i);
            if(i==len)
            {
                //printf("%d",i);
                //printf("3YES");
                return true;
            }
            for(j=i+1;j<=len;j++)
            {
                char *suffix  = (char *)malloc(len - i);
                    strncpy(suffix,s+i, j - i);
                suffix[j -i ] = '\0';
                //printf("\n%s",suffix);
                //printf("%d\n",j);

                if(wb[j]==false && dictionary_contains(suffix,dict)==true)
                {   wb[j]=true;
                    //  printf("%d",j);
                }

                if(j==len && wb[j]==true)
                {
                    //  printf("%s",suffix);
                    return true;
                }

        free(suffix);
            }
        }
        free(prefix);


    }
    return false;
}


int main(){
    int t,M,L,i;
    scanf("%d %d",&M,&L);
    char dict[1003][10];
    for (i = 0; i < M ;i++)  
        scanf("%s", dict[i]); 
    char string[100004];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%s",string);
        if( break_word(string, dict)==false)
            printf("NO\n");
        else
            printf("YES\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it shows the following error

Forbidden syscall rt_sigprocmask

Even though it works fine in my local compiler. What's the reason for it and how do I rectify it?

Comment: There is no obvious reason for your program to make such a call, but it could result from one or another of the calls to standard library functions.  If not, then it must relate to how the judge is building your code.  I don't see any change I can recommend to you to make your program avoid such a call.  Therefore, I suggest instead that you raise an issue against the online judge.

Comment: Here's a long shot: You have moderately large local variables (arrays) in `main()`.  These will be allocated on the stack.  To conserve virtual memory, Windows, and I think other OSes, impose limits both on how large the stack can grow, and on *how much further down* you can access something in the stack than the previous stack access -- the OS expects stack accesses to grow gradually downwards.  The default limits can be changed using linker switches, but you probably don't have access to them, so as a quick workaround, see if declaring these arrays `static` fixes the problem.